# what this code meaning after declaring the variable as bool type and !?

Tags: c, boolean, operators

hi guys after i saw a code that Dennis Ritchie wrote it but i did not understand what this mean
declaring more_space_toggle as (false) and after that (more_space_toggle = ! more_space_toggle) what does mean ? does it mean not operatore convert false to true or what ?
thank you for asnwerring me.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool more_space_toggle = false;

more_space_toggle = !more_space_toggle;
```

Answer (score 1):

`more_space_toggle = !more_space_toggle;` will toggle what the boolean is storing as `!` is the logical NOT operator. So if it currently stores `false`, it will toggle to `true`, and vice versa.

Comment: it's declared as false

Comment: @JosephA. If it is declared as `false` it will toggle to `true`

Answer (score 0):

! is logical NOT operator. Use this to reverse the logical state of its operand.

```
!true==false
```

or

```
!false==ture
```